# Motion JPG images on Django template

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I came across a requirement in Django, where I need to display group of JPG images in a series where it looks like streaming images. I found there is a solution in Flask, Reference url: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/video-streaming-with-flask . However, when I try to implement the same using Django, I am ending up with errors. Does any one help me in implementing this solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Provide what you've got so far...

Answer (score 0):

post the errors and your code, especially your views.py and your static urls in settings.py.

Comment: I am getting an error with mimetype is not recognizing where as in flask it is fine. I am pasting views.py code and settings file code

Comment: def video_feed(self):
    # mimetypes.init()
    # t = loader.get_template('FirstPage.html')
    return StreamingHttpResponse(gen(Camera()),
                    mimetype=('multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame'))

Comment: settings.py:STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    print('BASE_DIR: ---', BASE_DIR),
]